# Assemblies loaded twice in 64bit application

Tags: .net, clr

In x64 apps, it looks like some assemblies are being mapped into the process address space twice. The assemblies are loaded from the same location, in the same load context. There are no explicit reflection APIs or app domains involved.

This doesn't repro for native DLLs or framework DLLs that have native images (*.ni.dll), but does repro for locally-built assemblies, and others such as System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll and StyleCop.dll.

It does not repro when the solution is compiled for x86.

I'm seeing the duplicate entries in Process Explorer and VMMap. And when I break on module load in windbg I see different behavior when running x64 vs x86.

NGENing the assemblies does not make any difference.

To demonstrate, I put together a solution that builds an assembly and an executable that references that assembly. I can provide that code but it is dead simple: the assembly exposes an enum and the EXE references a value in that enum and prints it out.

When I build both assembly and EXE targetting x64 and run the EXE I see duplicate entries in VMMap and Process Explorer. Both show that the referenced assemblies are at the same path.
 VMMap shows .rsrc, .text, and Header sections for both entries (along with 3 Reserved blocks in each entry as well).

When I build the exact same solution targetting x86 and run the EXE I see 1 entry for the assembly in VMMap and Process Explorer.

I ran both the 32bit and 64bit versions under windbg with "sxe ld TestAssembly" to watch the loads of the offending assembly.

In the stacks below you'll see that there are 3 breaks in the 64bit version and only 2 in the 32bit version.

The first 2 stacks in the 64bit version look similar to the 2 in the 32bit version, but the 3rd is unique to 64bit.

Any ideas what's happening here? I know 64bit is 2x 32bit, but I didn't expect the assemblies to be loaded twice! :)

I've uploaded a solution to repro the problem here:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3C60C20A37311DB4!969&authkey=!AJWx4Cm3XDWeu2M

Included in that zip file are the repro steps, but if something is not clear please let me know!

In 64 bit, here are the stacks when the assembly is loaded under windbg (sxe ld TestAssembly):

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: C:\src\DualAssemblyLoadTest\bin\x64\Debug\DualAssemblyLoadTest.exe
 ...
 0:000> sxe ld TestAssembly
 0:000> g
 (15ac.a9c): Unknown exception - code 04242420 (first chance)
 ModLoad: 000007fe`f3cf0000 000007fe`f3cf6000   TestAssembly.dll
 ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection+0xa:
 00000000`77b0159a c3              ret
 0:000> k
 Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
 00000000`00498e38 000007fe`fdfd3c90 ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection+0xa
 00000000`00498e40 00000000`773f316d KERNELBASE!MapViewOfFileEx+0x90
 00000000`00498ec0 000007fe`f1558f22 KERNEL32!MapViewOfFileExStub+0x1d
 00000000`00498f00 000007fe`f155ac0a clr!CLRMapViewOfFileEx+0x42
 00000000`00498f80 000007fe`f155aa36 clr!MappedImageLayout::MappedImageLayout+0x166
 00000000`00499270 000007fe`f152ada9 clr!PEImageLayout::Map+0x47
 00000000`004992e0 000007fe`f152ad42 clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x5b6d5
 00000000`00499330 000007fe`f1518273 clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x5b5ba
 00000000`004993b0 000007fe`f1517c67 clr!RuntimeOpenImageInternal+0xc3
 00000000`00499480 000007fe`f1517b83 clr!GetAssemblyMDInternalImportEx+0xd9
 00000000`00499500 000007fe`f1565007 clr!CreateMetaDataImport+0x1b
 00000000`00499540 000007fe`f1564f69 clr!CAssemblyManifestImport::InitAndLoadMetaData+0x63
 00000000`00499590 000007fe`f1567b7f clr!CreateAssemblyManifestImport+0x99
 00000000`004995e0 000007fe`f156862d clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::CreateAssembly+0x110
 00000000`00499d90 000007fe`f1568243 clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::DoSetupRFS+0xc6
 00000000`0049a1a0 000007fe`f1567e1c clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::DoSetup+0x1d0
 00000000`0049a4b0 000007fe`f156672b clr!CAssemblyDownload::DoSetup+0xb8
 00000000`0049a550 000007fe`f1566615 clr!CAssemblyDownload::DownloadComplete+0xbb
 00000000`0049a5a0 000007fe`f1565094 clr!CAssemblyDownload::KickOffDownload+0x16d
 00000000`0049a880 000007fe`f151c5df clr!CAssemblyName::BindToObject+0x543
 00000000`0049a9d0 000007fe`f151c374 clr!FusionBind::RemoteLoad+0x1cf
 00000000`0049ab00 000007fe`f151c0ba clr!FusionBind::LoadAssembly+0x1d4
 00000000`0049ac20 000007fe`f151b3bd clr!AssemblySpec::FindAssemblyFile+0x116
 00000000`0049b3b0 000007fe`f1527ba4 clr!AppDomain::BindAssemblySpec+0x35e
 00000000`0049c5f0 000007fe`f15279fa clr!PEFile::LoadAssembly+0xe8
 00000000`0049c720 000007fe`f155b8fe clr!Module::LoadAssembly+0x361
 00000000`0049c9c0 000007fe`f14fd17b clr!Assembly::FindModuleByTypeRef+0x18f
 00000000`0049cd10 000007fe`f14f02d9 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x452
 00000000`0049ce50 000007fe`eeb0950e clr!CEEInfo::resolveToken+0xc58
 00000000`0049d520 000007fe`eeabaac7 clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode_Helper+0x1389
 00000000`0049d940 000007fe`eeabf316 clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode+0x1a7
 00000000`0049da10 000007fe`eeac0c65 clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR+0x186
 00000000`0049da70 000007fe`eeac0c06 clrjit!ReadProc+0x26
 00000000`0049dc40 000007fe`eeaa5d27 clrjit!THX_dop2_ReadProc+0x36
 00000000`0049dc70 000007fe`eeab732b clrjit!THX_dop2+0x77
 00000000`0049dcf0 000007fe`f15d07ee clrjit!PreJit::compileMethod+0x67
 00000000`0049dd70 000007fe`f15d073f clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0x6a
 00000000`0049ddc0 000007fe`f15d062e clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x8f
 00000000`0049de30 000007fe`f15d050c clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x46
 00000000`0049dec0 000007fe`f154e88a clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x23c
 00000000`0049e440 000007fe`f1500971 clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x4ea
 00000000`0049e690 000007fe`f14ffecb clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0xb1c
 00000000`0049eb70 000007fe`f14b24da clr!PreStubWorker+0x3eb
 00000000`0049ee70 000007fe`f14ff713 clr!ThePreStub+0x5a
 00000000`0049ef40 000007fe`f14ff242 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
 00000000`0049ef80 000007fe`f14ff30b clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
 00000000`0049efc0 000007fe`f169721c clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x2e6
 00000000`0049f170 000007fe`f1697976 clr!RunMain+0x1e7
 00000000`0049f340 000007fe`f1697870 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xb6
 00000000`0049f630 000007fe`f16973e6 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x45e
 00000000`0049fbf0 000007fe`f169733e clr!ExecuteEXE+0x3f
 00000000`0049fc60 000007fe`f1693ed4 clr!CorExeMainInternal+0xae
 00000000`0049fcf0 000007fe`f99c74e5 clr!CorExeMain+0x14
 00000000`0049fd30 000007fe`f9c65b21 mscoreei!CorExeMain+0xe0
 00000000`0049fd80 00000000`773e652d MSCOREE!CorExeMain_Exported+0x57
 00000000`0049fdb0 00000000`77adc521 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
 00000000`0049fde0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
 0:000> g
 ModLoad: 00000000`006b0000 00000000`006b6000   TestAssembly.dll
 ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection+0xa:
 00000000`77b0159a c3              ret
 0:000> k
 Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
 00000000`00498e38 000007fe`fdfd3c90 ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection+0xa
 00000000`00498e40 00000000`773f316d KERNELBASE!MapViewOfFileEx+0x90
 00000000`00498ec0 000007fe`f1558f22 KERNEL32!MapViewOfFileExStub+0x1d
 00000000`00498f00 000007fe`f155ac6b clr!CLRMapViewOfFileEx+0x42
 00000000`00498f80 000007fe`f155aa36 clr!MappedImageLayout::MappedImageLayout+0x1c7
 00000000`00499270 000007fe`f152ada9 clr!PEImageLayout::Map+0x47
 00000000`004992e0 000007fe`f152ad42 clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x5b6d5
 00000000`00499330 000007fe`f1518273 clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x5b5ba
 00000000`004993b0 000007fe`f1517c67 clr!RuntimeOpenImageInternal+0xc3
 00000000`00499480 000007fe`f1517b83 clr!GetAssemblyMDInternalImportEx+0xd9
 00000000`00499500 000007fe`f1565007 clr!CreateMetaDataImport+0x1b
 00000000`00499540 000007fe`f1564f69 clr!CAssemblyManifestImport::InitAndLoadMetaData+0x63
 00000000`00499590 000007fe`f1567b7f clr!CreateAssemblyManifestImport+0x99
 00000000`004995e0 000007fe`f156862d clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::CreateAssembly+0x110
 00000000`00499d90 000007fe`f1568243 clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::DoSetupRFS+0xc6
 00000000`0049a1a0 000007fe`f1567e1c clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::DoSetup+0x1d0
 00000000`0049a4b0 000007fe`f156672b clr!CAssemblyDownload::DoSetup+0xb8
 00000000`0049a550 000007fe`f1566615 clr!CAssemblyDownload::DownloadComplete+0xbb
 00000000`0049a5a0 000007fe`f1565094 clr!CAssemblyDownload::KickOffDownload+0x16d
 00000000`0049a880 000007fe`f151c5df clr!CAssemblyName::BindToObject+0x543
 00000000`0049a9d0 000007fe`f151c374 clr!FusionBind::RemoteLoad+0x1cf
 00000000`0049ab00 000007fe`f151c0ba clr!FusionBind::LoadAssembly+0x1d4
 00000000`0049ac20 000007fe`f151b3bd clr!AssemblySpec::FindAssemblyFile+0x116
 00000000`0049b3b0 000007fe`f1527ba4 clr!AppDomain::BindAssemblySpec+0x35e
 00000000`0049c5f0 000007fe`f15279fa clr!PEFile::LoadAssembly+0xe8
 00000000`0049c720 000007fe`f155b8fe clr!Module::LoadAssembly+0x361
 00000000`0049c9c0 000007fe`f14fd17b clr!Assembly::FindModuleByTypeRef+0x18f
 00000000`0049cd10 000007fe`f14f02d9 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x452
 00000000`0049ce50 000007fe`eeb0950e clr!CEEInfo::resolveToken+0xc58
 00000000`0049d520 000007fe`eeabaac7 clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode_Helper+0x1389
 00000000`0049d940 000007fe`eeabf316 clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode+0x1a7
 00000000`0049da10 000007fe`eeac0c65 clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR+0x186
 00000000`0049da70 000007fe`eeac0c06 clrjit!ReadProc+0x26
 00000000`0049dc40 000007fe`eeaa5d27 clrjit!THX_dop2_ReadProc+0x36
 00000000`0049dc70 000007fe`eeab732b clrjit!THX_dop2+0x77
 00000000`0049dcf0 000007fe`f15d07ee clrjit!PreJit::compileMethod+0x67
 00000000`0049dd70 000007fe`f15d073f clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0x6a
 00000000`0049ddc0 000007fe`f15d062e clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x8f
 00000000`0049de30 000007fe`f15d050c clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x46
 00000000`0049dec0 000007fe`f154e88a clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x23c
 00000000`0049e440 000007fe`f1500971 clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x4ea
 00000000`0049e690 000007fe`f14ffecb clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0xb1c
 00000000`0049eb70 000007fe`f14b24da clr!PreStubWorker+0x3eb
 00000000`0049ee70 000007fe`f14ff713 clr!ThePreStub+0x5a
 00000000`0049ef40 000007fe`f14ff242 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
 00000000`0049ef80 000007fe`f14ff30b clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
 00000000`0049efc0 000007fe`f169721c clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x2e6
 00000000`0049f170 000007fe`f1697976 clr!RunMain+0x1e7
 00000000`0049f340 000007fe`f1697870 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xb6
 00000000`0049f630 000007fe`f16973e6 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x45e
 00000000`0049fbf0 000007fe`f169733e clr!ExecuteEXE+0x3f
 00000000`0049fc60 000007fe`f1693ed4 clr!CorExeMainInternal+0xae
 00000000`0049fcf0 000007fe`f99c74e5 clr!CorExeMain+0x14
 00000000`0049fd30 000007fe`f9c65b21 mscoreei!CorExeMain+0xe0
 00000000`0049fd80 00000000`773e652d MSCOREE!CorExeMain_Exported+0x57
 00000000`0049fdb0 00000000`77adc521 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
 00000000`0049fde0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
 0:000> g
 ModLoad: 000007fe`f3cf0000 000007fe`f3cf6000   C:\src\DualAssemblyLoadTest\bin\x64\Debug\TestAssembly.dll
 ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection+0xa:
 00000000`77b0159a c3              ret
 0:000> k
 Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
 00000000`0049b468 00000000`77aeacfc ntdll!ZwMapViewOfSection+0xa
 00000000`0049b470 00000000`77ae1327 ntdll!LdrpMapViewOfSection+0xbc
 00000000`0049b520 00000000`77ad7cc8 ntdll!LdrpFindOrMapDll+0x469
 00000000`0049b6a0 00000000`77ad7b2e ntdll!LdrpLoadDll+0x148
 00000000`0049b8b0 000007fe`fdfcc71f ntdll!LdrLoadDll+0x9a
 00000000`0049b920 000007fe`f150bf54 KERNELBASE!LoadLibraryExW+0x22e
 00000000`0049b990 000007fe`f150bec1 clr!CLRLoadLibraryEx+0xfc
 00000000`0049b9e0 000007fe`f152c30f clr!CLRLoadLibraryEx+0x51
 00000000`0049ba30 000007fe`f152c264 clr!LoadedImageLayout::LoadedImageLayout+0x9e
 00000000`0049bce0 000007fe`f155b133 clr!PEImageLayout::Load+0x3d
 00000000`0049bd20 000007fe`f155af5e clr!PEImage::Load+0x119
 00000000`0049bda0 000007fe`f152372c clr!PEFile::LoadLibrary+0xe2
 00000000`0049bdd0 000007fe`f15236cf clr!DomainFile::LoadLibrary+0x59
 00000000`0049be20 000007fe`f1521078 clr!DomainFile::DoIncrementalLoad+0xf6
 00000000`0049be50 000007fe`f1521463 clr!AppDomain::TryIncrementalLoad+0x145
 00000000`0049c250 000007fe`f1519c38 clr!AppDomain::LoadDomainFile+0x167
 00000000`0049c310 000007fe`f1519a7b clr!AppDomain::LoadDomainAssemblyInternal+0x178
 00000000`0049c400 000007fe`f1527a9c clr!AppDomain::LoadDomainAssembly+0x8c
 00000000`0049c720 000007fe`f155b8fe clr!Module::LoadAssembly+0x403
 00000000`0049c9c0 000007fe`f14fd17b clr!Assembly::FindModuleByTypeRef+0x18f
 00000000`0049cd10 000007fe`f14f02d9 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x452
 00000000`0049ce50 000007fe`eeb0950e clr!CEEInfo::resolveToken+0xc58
 00000000`0049d520 000007fe`eeabaac7 clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode_Helper+0x1389
 00000000`0049d940 000007fe`eeabf316 clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode+0x1a7
 00000000`0049da10 000007fe`eeac0c65 clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR+0x186
 00000000`0049da70 000007fe`eeac0c06 clrjit!ReadProc+0x26
 00000000`0049dc40 000007fe`eeaa5d27 clrjit!THX_dop2_ReadProc+0x36
 00000000`0049dc70 000007fe`eeab732b clrjit!THX_dop2+0x77
 00000000`0049dcf0 000007fe`f15d07ee clrjit!PreJit::compileMethod+0x67
 00000000`0049dd70 000007fe`f15d073f clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0x6a
 00000000`0049ddc0 000007fe`f15d062e clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x8f
 00000000`0049de30 000007fe`f15d050c clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x46
 00000000`0049dec0 000007fe`f154e88a clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x23c
 00000000`0049e440 000007fe`f1500971 clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x4ea
 00000000`0049e690 000007fe`f14ffecb clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0xb1c
 00000000`0049eb70 000007fe`f14b24da clr!PreStubWorker+0x3eb
 00000000`0049ee70 000007fe`f14ff713 clr!ThePreStub+0x5a
 00000000`0049ef40 000007fe`f14ff242 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
 00000000`0049ef80 000007fe`f14ff30b clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
 00000000`0049efc0 000007fe`f169721c clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x2e6
 00000000`0049f170 000007fe`f1697976 clr!RunMain+0x1e7
 00000000`0049f340 000007fe`f1697870 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xb6
 00000000`0049f630 000007fe`f16973e6 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x45e
 00000000`0049fbf0 000007fe`f169733e clr!ExecuteEXE+0x3f
 00000000`0049fc60 000007fe`f1693ed4 clr!CorExeMainInternal+0xae
 00000000`0049fcf0 000007fe`f99c74e5 clr!CorExeMain+0x14
 00000000`0049fd30 000007fe`f9c65b21 mscoreei!CorExeMain+0xe0
 00000000`0049fd80 00000000`773e652d MSCOREE!CorExeMain_Exported+0x57
 00000000`0049fdb0 00000000`77adc521 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
 00000000`0049fde0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
 0:000> g
```

In 32 bit, here are the stacks when the assembly is loaded under windbg (sxe ld TestAssembly):

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: bin\x86\Debug\DualAssemblyLoadTest.exe
 ...
 0:000> sxe ld TestAssembly
 0:000> g
 (14cc.15fc): Unknown exception - code 04242420 (first chance)
 ModLoad: 60350000 60358000   TestAssembly.dll
 eax=00000000 ebx=0084a1fc ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
 eip=77cafc42 esp=0042adac ebp=0042ade4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
 cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
 ntdll!NtMapViewOfSection+0x12:
 77cafc42 83c404          add     esp,4
 0:000> k
 ChildEBP RetAddr  
0042adac 7720e231 ntdll!NtMapViewOfSection+0x12
 0042ade4 6e337b8d KERNELBASE!MapViewOfFileEx+0x81
 0042ae3c 6e337d52 clr!CLRMapViewOfFileEx+0x26
 0042b0ac 6e337e7c clr!MappedImageLayout::MappedImageLayout+0x200
 0042b0f4 6e335ca1 clr!PEImageLayout::Map+0x2c
 0042b12c 6e335d3e clr!PEImage::GetLayoutInternal+0x106
 0042b17c 6e3320e6 clr!PEImage::GetLayout+0xf0
 0042b200 6e33300f clr!RuntimeOpenImageInternal+0x9d
 0042b250 6e35a512 clr!GetAssemblyMDInternalImportEx+0xe6
 0042b288 6e35a5c6 clr!CAssemblyManifestImport::InitAndLoadMetaData+0x59
 0042b2bc 6e35ca67 clr!CreateAssemblyManifestImport+0x50
 0042b97c 6e35d240 clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::CreateAssembly+0x20a
 0042bce4 6e35cf5e clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::DoSetupRFS+0xbf
 0042bf9c 6e35cd0b clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::DoSetup+0x22f
 0042bffc 6e35a6d7 clr!CAssemblyDownload::DoSetup+0xa4
 0042c03c 6e35a894 clr!CAssemblyDownload::DownloadComplete+0x103
 0042c2b0 6e35a920 clr!CAssemblyDownload::KickOffDownload+0x33a
 0042c350 6e32784b clr!CAssemblyName::BindToObject+0x9c1
 0042c3ec 6e327a7d clr!FusionBind::RemoteLoad+0x1fc
 0042c478 6e327c30 clr!FusionBind::LoadAssembly+0x17c
 0042cb54 6e327e6f clr!AssemblySpec::FindAssemblyFile+0x104
 0042d87c 6e325299 clr!AppDomain::BindAssemblySpec+0xffd
 0042d934 6e325103 clr!PEFile::LoadAssembly+0xc0
 0042da08 6e3252e4 clr!Module::LoadAssembly+0x176
 0042dca8 6e2f91ca clr!Assembly::FindModuleByTypeRef+0x1f5
 0042dd14 6e304c27 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x103
 0042ddbc 751d10cf clr!CEEInfo::resolveToken+0x306
 0042ddcc 751fffe8 clrjit!Compiler::impResolveToken+0x3a
 0042e4fc 751d1a60 clrjit!Compiler::impImportBlockCode+0x42f5
 0042e57c 751d1c42 clrjit!Compiler::impImportBlock+0x5d
 0042e594 751d244d clrjit!Compiler::impImport+0x1ea
 0042e5b4 751d401c clrjit!Compiler::compCompile+0x63
 0042e5f0 751d4132 clrjit!Compiler::compCompileHelper+0x2fa
 0042e668 751d4282 clrjit!Compiler::compCompile+0x213
 0042e758 751d4595 clrjit!jitNativeCode+0x1cc
 0042e77c 6e303669 clrjit!CILJit::compileMethod+0x25
 0042e7cc 6e303701 clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0x41
 0042e80c 6e303743 clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x31
 0042e870 6e30399c clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x2a
 0042ec08 6e303496 clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x3ca
 0042ecec 6e3040db clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x3a9
 0042ed60 6e2ebcd5 clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0x59d
 0042edc8 6e2d2ae9 clr!PreStubWorker+0xed
 0042edf8 6e2d2652 clr!ThePreStub+0x16
 0042ee04 6e2e264f clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x34
 0042ee58 6e2e2e95 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x6b
 0042eed0 6e3974ec clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x152
 0042effc 6e397610 clr!RunMain+0x1aa
 0042f270 6e421dc4 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0x124
 0042f774 6e421e67 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x614
 0042f7d0 6e421f7a clr!ExecuteEXE+0x4c
 0042f810 6e42416a clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xdc
 0042f84c 70e2f5a3 clr!_CorExeMain+0x4d
 0042f888 70ea7f16 mscoreei!_CorExeMain+0x10a
 0042f898 70ea4de3 MSCOREE!ShellShim__CorExeMain+0x99
 0042f8a0 7574339a MSCOREE!_CorExeMain_Exported+0x8
 0042f8ac 77cc9ef2 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
 0042f8ec 77cc9ec5 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
 0042f904 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
 0:000> g
 ModLoad: 001e0000 001e8000   TestAssembly.dll
 eax=00000000 ebx=0084a1fc ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
 eip=77cafc42 esp=0042adac ebp=0042ade4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
 cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
 ntdll!NtMapViewOfSection+0x12:
 77cafc42 83c404          add     esp,4
 0:000> k
 ChildEBP RetAddr  
0042adac 7720e231 ntdll!NtMapViewOfSection+0x12
 0042ade4 6e337b8d KERNELBASE!MapViewOfFileEx+0x81
 0042ae3c 6e337d7d clr!CLRMapViewOfFileEx+0x26
 0042b0ac 6e337e7c clr!MappedImageLayout::MappedImageLayout+0x227
 0042b0f4 6e335ca1 clr!PEImageLayout::Map+0x2c
 0042b12c 6e335d3e clr!PEImage::GetLayoutInternal+0x106
 0042b17c 6e3320e6 clr!PEImage::GetLayout+0xf0
 0042b200 6e33300f clr!RuntimeOpenImageInternal+0x9d
 0042b250 6e35a512 clr!GetAssemblyMDInternalImportEx+0xe6
 0042b288 6e35a5c6 clr!CAssemblyManifestImport::InitAndLoadMetaData+0x59
 0042b2bc 6e35ca67 clr!CreateAssemblyManifestImport+0x50
 0042b97c 6e35d240 clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::CreateAssembly+0x20a
 0042bce4 6e35cf5e clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::DoSetupRFS+0xbf
 0042bf9c 6e35cd0b clr!CAsmDownloadMgr::DoSetup+0x22f
 0042bffc 6e35a6d7 clr!CAssemblyDownload::DoSetup+0xa4
 0042c03c 6e35a894 clr!CAssemblyDownload::DownloadComplete+0x103
 0042c2b0 6e35a920 clr!CAssemblyDownload::KickOffDownload+0x33a
 0042c350 6e32784b clr!CAssemblyName::BindToObject+0x9c1
 0042c3ec 6e327a7d clr!FusionBind::RemoteLoad+0x1fc
 0042c478 6e327c30 clr!FusionBind::LoadAssembly+0x17c
 0042cb54 6e327e6f clr!AssemblySpec::FindAssemblyFile+0x104
 0042d87c 6e325299 clr!AppDomain::BindAssemblySpec+0xffd
 0042d934 6e325103 clr!PEFile::LoadAssembly+0xc0
 0042da08 6e3252e4 clr!Module::LoadAssembly+0x176
 0042dca8 6e2f91ca clr!Assembly::FindModuleByTypeRef+0x1f5
 0042dd14 6e304c27 clr!ClassLoader::LoadTypeDefOrRefThrowing+0x103
 0042ddbc 751d10cf clr!CEEInfo::resolveToken+0x306
 0042ddcc 751fffe8 clrjit!Compiler::impResolveToken+0x3a
 0042e4fc 751d1a60 clrjit!Compiler::impImportBlockCode+0x42f5
 0042e57c 751d1c42 clrjit!Compiler::impImportBlock+0x5d
 0042e594 751d244d clrjit!Compiler::impImport+0x1ea
 0042e5b4 751d401c clrjit!Compiler::compCompile+0x63
 0042e5f0 751d4132 clrjit!Compiler::compCompileHelper+0x2fa
 0042e668 751d4282 clrjit!Compiler::compCompile+0x213
 0042e758 751d4595 clrjit!jitNativeCode+0x1cc
 0042e77c 6e303669 clrjit!CILJit::compileMethod+0x25
 0042e7cc 6e303701 clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0x41
 0042e80c 6e303743 clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x31
 0042e870 6e30399c clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x2a
 0042ec08 6e303496 clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x3ca
 0042ecec 6e3040db clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x3a9
 0042ed60 6e2ebcd5 clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0x59d
 0042edc8 6e2d2ae9 clr!PreStubWorker+0xed
 0042edf8 6e2d2652 clr!ThePreStub+0x16
 0042ee04 6e2e264f clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x34
 0042ee58 6e2e2e95 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x6b
 0042eed0 6e3974ec clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x152
 0042effc 6e397610 clr!RunMain+0x1aa
 0042f270 6e421dc4 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0x124
 0042f774 6e421e67 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x614
 0042f7d0 6e421f7a clr!ExecuteEXE+0x4c
 0042f810 6e42416a clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xdc
 0042f84c 70e2f5a3 clr!_CorExeMain+0x4d
 0042f888 70ea7f16 mscoreei!_CorExeMain+0x10a
 0042f898 70ea4de3 MSCOREE!ShellShim__CorExeMain+0x99
 0042f8a0 7574339a MSCOREE!_CorExeMain_Exported+0x8
 0042f8ac 77cc9ef2 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
 0042f8ec 77cc9ec5 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
 0042f904 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
 0:000> g
```

Here's the information from VMMap showing one assembly loaded twice in the process, with the same sections loaded both times.

```
Address            Type           Size       Committed  Private   Total WS  Private WS  Shareable WS  Shared WS  Locked WS  Blocks  Protection              Details                                                                                                 
 00000000006B0000   Image (ASLR)   24         12                   8                     8             8                     6       Execute/Read            C:\src\DualAssemblyLoadTest\bin\x64\Debug\TestAssembly.dll
   00000000006B1000 Image (ASLR)   4                                                                                                 Reserved               
   00000000006B3000 Image (ASLR)   4                                                                                                 Reserved               
   00000000006B5000 Image (ASLR)   4                                                                                                 Reserved               
   00000000006B4000 Image (ASLR)   4          4                                                                                      Read                    .rsrc
   00000000006B2000 Image (ASLR)   4          4                    4                     4             4                             Execute/Read            .text
   00000000006B0000 Image (ASLR)   4          4                    4                     4             4                             Read                    Header

000007FEF3CF0000   Image (ASLR)   24         12                   8                     8             8                     6       Execute/Read            C:\src\DualAssemblyLoadTest\bin\x64\Debug\TestAssembly.dll
   000007FEF3CF1000 Image (ASLR)   4                                                                                                 Reserved               
   000007FEF3CF3000 Image (ASLR)   4                                                                                                 Reserved               
   000007FEF3CF5000 Image (ASLR)   4                                                                                                 Reserved               
   000007FEF3CF4000 Image (ASLR)   4          4                                                                                      Read                    .rsrc
   000007FEF3CF2000 Image (ASLR)   4          4                    4                     4             4                             Execute/Read            .text
   000007FEF3CF0000 Image (ASLR)   4          4                    4                     4             4                             Read                    Header
```

**Update (20.Jan.2014):**

The CLR team responded to my [Connect post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780964/assemblies-loaded-twice-in-64bit-application):

"Thanks for reporting this issue. We have fixed it for the next major release of the .NET Framework."

Comment: It is not loaded twice, just mapped twice.  Note how the DLL header is mapped differently if you leave it at AnyCPU, from private to sharable workingset.  I think this is just a side-effect of the CLR having to patch the image header to make it a 64-bit module.

Comment: True about mapping. I should have been more precise. It seems that there's more that just the header being mapped, though. The assembly loaded in the above VMMap output is <4KB, but its image is committing 24KB. In my real app I have 17 assemblies totalling 1.8MB in disk, but committing 4.1MB in memory. Another app is loading a 35MB assembly (don't ask) which is committing 140MB.

Comment: So its a bug whenever it appears twice? I'm seeing this with native COM dlls

Comment: It depends. Hans suggests some reasons why it would be mapped twice which may be what you're seeing. In my case there was a CLR bug. I'd need to look deeper at your scenario to know what was going on. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried investigating Fusion logs?